# How to make types for indexing

Tags: c++, typedef

I have something like:

Array definition:

```
array<array<Value, N_FOO_PER_BAR>, N_BAR> arr;
```

Access function:

```
Value getFoo(int barIdx, int fooIdx){
  return arr[barIdx][fooIdx];
}
```

For-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N_BAR; i ++){
  for(int j = 0; j < N_FOO_PER_BAR; j ++){
    arr[i][j].doSomething();
  }
}
```

**Problem:** Indices for foo and bar can easily get mixed up when using `getFoo(...)`.

I would like to define a type `BarIdx` and `FooIdx` and then the compiler should complain when I mix them up.

The access function would then look like:

```
function getFoo(BadIdx barIdx, FooIdx fooIdx){
  return arr[barIdx][fooIdx];
}
```

The for-loop could look like:

```
for(BarIdx i = 0; i < N_BAR; i ++){
  for(FooIdx j = 0; j < N_FOO_PER_BAR; j ++){
    arr[i][j].doSomething();
  }
}
```

So I'm looking how to define a type which (a) will issue a warning/error when used at the wrong place but (b) still behaves as much as an integer as possible, for for loop and array access with []. This should also work on CUDA, so I would prefer to use simple language constructs rather than a perfect solution.

Comment: I personally think it's a non-issue in this case, but maybe [boost::units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) can help you out.

Comment: Shoudn't `function getFoo(...)` be written `Value getFoo(...)` ? kinda obvious but maybe not for everybody. Interesting question anyhow.

Comment: @kebs, that's what happens when you use too many programming languages at the same time. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty with doing this is that you can't simply [inherit from int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143020/why-cant-i-inherit-from-int-in-c) in C++, so you need to provide a wrapper which not only implicitly converts to and from `int`, but also provides all the necessary operators so that you can do things like:

```
BarIdx a = 0;
++a;
```

You might want to start with something simple like this:

```
template <typename T>
class IntegralWrapper {
    T value;
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    IntegralWrapper() :value() {}
    IntegralWrapper(T v) :value(v) {}
    operator T() const { return value; }
};
```

Then add any operators you need later. You would then define your index classes like this:

```
class BarIdx : public IntegralWrapper<int> {};
class FooIdx : public IntegralWrapper<int> {};
```

Alternatively, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f5566f15c11c52e2db7189d602cc601a-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) is a seemingly pretty complete integral wrapper solution taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793298/c-class-wrapper-around-fundamental-types) which you could probably use.

Comment: Can I expect that the compiler will implement this as efficient as a plain int?

Comment: You might get a small efficiency hit, but all the operators should get inlined, so I doubt it would be too bad. Only way to find out is to try it and measure.

Answer (score 2):

It will not trivial. The problems is not in defining the type for index, but that the `operator []` of the array take `size_type` (`std::size_t`) which will reduce to null all your effort to differenciate the indexes.

I will suggest another kind of sintactic sugar:

```
struct Idx {int bar, foo;};
```

Access function:

```
Value& getValue(Idx i){
  return arr[i.bar][i.foo];
}
```

For-loop:

```
for(Idx i{0,0} ; i.bar < N_BAR; i.bar ++){
  for(i.foo = 0; i.foo < N_FOO_PER_BAR; i.foo ++){
    getValue(i).doSomething();
  }
}
```

but also:

```
for(auto &foos : arr){
  for(auto &foo : foos){
    foo.doSomething();
  }
}
```