# When I use typedef or using for an int, how much is it still an int?

Tags: c++, typedef, using

I tried the following:

```
using Idx = int;
array<Value, N> arr;

for(Idx i = 0; i < N; i ++){
  arr[i].doSomething();
}
```

I expected that the compiler would issue a warning or an error when I try to use `Idx` as if it was an `int`. But it does not.

So, when I use `using` or `typedef` to alias type A as a B, are variables of type B still also of type A, and vice versa? So that no type safety can be achieved by renaming a type when it looks the same but has a different meaning.

(This is related to the following question I recently asked: [How to make types for indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641165/how-to-make-types-for-indexing))

Comment: The keyword here is the word [*"alias"*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alias), meaning `Idx` (in your case) is just another name for `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alias declaration or `typedef` just makes a new name for the aliased type. `Idx` is not a different type from `int` in this case; they can be used interchangeably with no difference in semantics.

From [dcl.typedef] (emphasis mine):

> A name declared with the typedef specifier becomes a typedef-name. Within the scope of its declaration, a
>   typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in
>   the way described in Clause 8. **A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type. A typedef-name does
>   not introduce a new type the way a class declaration or enum declaration does.**

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` and equivalent `using` statements do not add any type safety in that they introduce alternative identifiers for the *same* type.

Sometimes it is desirable to create distinct types easily, and you may come across things like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t Id>
struct Distinct_Type
{
    explicit Distinct_Type(const T& t) : t_(t) { }
    const T& get() const { return t_; }
    ...whatever else...
    T t_;
};
```

And usage like:

```
typedef Distinct_Type<int, __LINE__> Age;
void f(Age);
void g() { f(Age(88)); /*forced explicit construction*/ }
```

Clearly `__LINE__` is a nasty and error prone hack: with C++11 it's possible to create compile time incrementing values that work reliably, but the code's too long for recreation and inclusion here - google if interested.

These really-distinct types have problems though: for example, if you call a function like `template <typename T> void f(T t);` ala `f(Distinct_Type<int, 1>(1));`, `f(Distinct_Type<int, 2>(1));`, `f(Distinct_Type<int, 3>(1));` - the compiler/linker may or may not eliminate two of the three instantiations from the executable image, reducing code bloat.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have a simple way of deriving classes from built-in types, especially if automatic conversions were disabled. For example one could define distinct integer classes for feet and meters, preventing errors like the one which led to the [Mars Orbiter Crash in 1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure). Ada with its focus on safety [provides that feature](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/range). The reason why it is not possible in C++ is provided in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143734/3150802) (the OP there tried to explicitly inherit from int): The C type system for ints is so "chaotic" (Stroustrup) that it makes these types unsuitable for building blocks in a class hierarchy.

As it is in C++, one must write a wrapper including all the operations one wants to have, which are provided automatically in the case of Ada.