# Defining a structure of nonzero integers

Tags: c, types

Let's say we wanted to define integer division to exclude division by zero.  Is it possible to do so?  I want something that looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* Define a structure intn0. */
typedef struct intn0 intn0;

struct intn0{
    int x;
    /* assert(x != 0); */
};

int div(int a, intn0 b){
    return a / b.x;
};
```

Obviously, this doesn't work.  Is there a way to perform this sort of assertion on the structure level, say, for the purpose of defining a division function such that for all valid inputs (i.e. inputs of the correct type), we can guarantee it will generate a valid output without error and without garbage?

If you can't do this in C, what language would allow this sort of abstraction (preferably something similar to C rather than something like Haskell)?

Comment: What do you mean "exclude"? What would be the expected behaviour?

Comment: You can probably write a function that returns your int, or errors if the input argument is 0. Use that as an initialization function: `int a = init_int(5);`.

Comment: or C++, and throw an exception if the value is not 0

Comment: You cannot *"guarantee it will generate a valid output"* since the result is undefined.

Comment: @rbaghbanli I was hoping that an input would throw some sort of type error.  I understand this behavior is built in to division, but it's not hard to imagine another function where I would want this behavior.  The nice thing about making this built into structures means that I can chain together arbitrary functions without worrying about inducing an error, as long as they are properly typed.  This is not for the purpose of error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to perform this sort of assertion on the structure level, say,

Assertions correspond (when enabled) to executable code.  You cannot embed assertions into data structures in C, though you can do in Java or C++ (for example), by making the members of a class private and protecting all means of setting them with code that tests the validity (as defined by the class) of the proposed value.  As @RSahu observes, you can do similar in C, though the language doesn't provide a means to actually *enforce* it.

Under some circumstances, however, it is possible to define a data structure that has no representation for values that you do not want it to represent.  For example:

```
/*
 * Represents a non-zero integer between -(UINT_MAX+1) and (UINT_MAX+1),
 * inclusive; has no representation for zero.
 */
struct intn0 {
    _Bool is_negative;
    unsigned n_less_one;
};
```

> for the purpose of defining a division function such that for all valid inputs (i.e. inputs of the correct type), we can guarantee it will generate a valid output without error and without garbage?

Integer division with the above struct type might look like this:

```
int div(int a, struct intn0 b){
    return (b.is_negative ? -1 : 1) * (a / ((long long) b.n_less_one + 1));
};
```

Supposing that type `long long` is large enough to represent `UINT_MAX + 1`, that will never have a division by zero and will always produce a consistent and reasonable result for every possible pair of arguments.  If the division semantics are not exactly what you want, then I'm sure you could tweak them to suit.

Comment: I think the first thing you have to do is define ERR_MSG since both -1 and 0 can be a valid quotient ; then **float divide(float num,float dem){if (! dem) return(ERR_MSG); else return( num / dem ); }**

Comment: @ArifBurhan, this approach does not afford a way to represent `0` as a divisor (that's the point), but it handles `-1` as a divisor just fine.  This `struct intn0` provides a sign / magnitude integer representation, where the magnitude is recorded as an *`unsigned`* value one less than the absolute value of the integer to which the struct corresponds.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to perform this sort of assertion on the structure level,

You can do that if you use an opaque pointer.

.h file:

```
// Declare the struct but don't define it in the .h file.
typedef struct intn0 intn0;

intn0* create_intn0(int val);

int get_value(intn0* intPtr);
```

.c file:

```
#include "***.h" // Use an appropriate name for the .h file.

// Define the struct so that functions in the .c file can use it.
struct intn0 { int n; };

intn0* create_intn0(int val)
{
   assert(val != 0);
   intn0* intPtr = malloc(sizeof(*intPtr));
   assert(intPtr  != NULL);
   intPtr->n = val;
   return intPtr;
}

int get_value(intn0* intPtr)
{
   assert(intPtr != NULL);
   return intPtr->n;
}
```

Comment: GCC is throwing me an error on the memory allocation step with the message "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'malloc'".

Comment: @AndrewSalmon, that should've been `malloc(sizeof(*intPtr))`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a reasonable expectation for C structures (without it being more trouble than it's worth). You could potentially switch to C++ and write a custom integer class, but you're going to need a lot of code to implement all the normal behaviors of an `int` (you [can't inherit from int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2143020/2615940)).

Your best bet would be to just define a custom division function:

```
int zero_safe_div(int a, int b){

    if (b != 0)
        return a / b;
    else
         /* return zero or whatever behavior you want in this case */
}
```

Since you seem open to other languages, you could also use Python, which allows you to inherit from an `int` type (since it's just a class like everything else in Python):

```
class safe_div_int(int):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __div__(self, rhv):
        if rhv != 0:
            return self.val / rhv
        else:
            return 0 # this could be replaced with whatever behavior you want for the 
                     # zero division case

v1 = safe_div_int(3)

print("V1: {}".format(v1))
print("V1 / 5.0: {}".format(v1 / 5.0))
print("V1 + 5: {}".format(v1 + 5))
print("V1 / 0: {}".format(v1 / 0))
```

This code produces this output:

> V1: 3
>   V1 / 5.0: 0.6
>   V1 + 5: 8
>   V1 / 0: 0